How much risk do I incur forwarding a random port to my server IFF the request comes from a specific MAC address?
I'm setting up a Nextcloud server for my own personal use, and don't really care to get a domain name or SSL certificate (maybe I'll make my own :grin:).
That being said, I'd like to forward a random port number to the server if and only if the request to that port comes from a specific MAC address (any one of the addresses of my devices).
As someone who's never done this before, are there any otherwise common-knowledge gotchas that I'm ignorant of by doing this?
I understand that there's non-zero risk by opening anything up to the internet, and while my intuition says this is pretty safe, I don't know what I don't know.

(Potential?) Risks

AFAIK, IPv6 addresses come from MAC addresses. Maybe someone could figure the (internal?) IPv6 address of my server and use that to determine the MAC address to spoof
In a similar way, someone could see any of my device's IPv6 addresses and use one of those to determine which MAC address to spoof

Perhaps I can mitigate both (1) and (2) by only accepting/forwarding IPv4 requests




What exactly do you mean by "forward"? As in setting up port forwarding on your router, exposing a service on a LAN host to the Internet? In that case why would MAC addresses of your devices be relevant? The source MAC address in the frames would essentially always be that of the "WAN (default) gateway".

@TomYan Setting up port forwarding on my router, yes. The MAC address of my devices would be relevant because my router's OS allows me to conditionally port forward, one of those conditions being the requesting device's MAC address. That is, I can say "If you receive a request targeting this port, forward it if and only if the requesting device has a MAC address of... otherwise, reject it like you would all others."

You don't seem to know how "IP/L3 forwarding" works? It is not a matter of what your router allows.

@TomYan I'd be happy to do some reading or something if you''ve got any. As far as everything I've read, it is a matter of what my router allows. The router routes traffic to devices on my internal network, and how it routes traffic can be determined via e.g. port forwarding rules. Again, I'm aware that I'm fairly new to this so I'm happy to get learned. Or, better yet, happy to accept a suitable answer to my question :)

@TomYan Are you saying that MAC address is only relevant in forwarding traffic that's coming from what's already in my local network?

So a mac address is only pertinent to a specific LAN. When traffic sent by the device that has that mac address crosses a router to another network, the MAC address is rewritten for that network *usually using the exit interface on the router. as such a router can only make decisions based on mac address if it is on one of the networks directly connected to the router. otherwise the mac address will have been rewritten (likely many many times) between source and destination.

Knowlege of your MAC address is useless. Even if somebody does spoof your MAC address it wouldn't do them any good. MAC Addresses are only pseudo unique. You can't forward a port to a client outside of your network.  MAC addresses outside of your own network isn't helpful information. Why are you worried about MAC addresses being spoofed?

@FrankThomas Ah! Thank you that makes total sense. Looks like I had the wrong idea
